# how to see the log of the DEBUGMSGTL in net-snmp

Tags: snmp, agent, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to write a snmp subagent that using agentX, which is supported by net-snmp.
At first, I used the example codes from net-snmp FAQ:

http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent

And from the example codes
(**example-demon.c,nstAgentSubagentObject.c,nstAgentSubagentObject.h**), I build a subagent which can use agentX to perform snmpget and snmpset.

My question is:
From the code in **nstAgentSubagentObject.c**, there are many trace codes such as follows:

```
DEBUGMSGTL(("nstAgentSubagentObject",
                "Initializing the nstAgentSubagentObject module\n"));
```

But I can't see the log anywhere.

I tried to start snmpd (demon of snmp) by 
`snmpd -f -DnstAgentSubagentObject -Lf /tmp/snmp.log`.

But I still can't see the log. Could anyone tell me how to see the log of DEBUGMSGTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting `snmpd` with `-D nstAgentSubagentObject` you want to pass that command-line option to your subagent when you start it.

In the tutorial it suggests starting the subagent with the following command:

```
% ./mysubagent &
```

To enable the more debug messages, try starting it with the following command instead:

```
% ./mysubagent -D nstAgentSubagentObject
```

If I remember correctly, that should print out the debug output to the console.  You can combine it with the `-L` option if you'd prefer it written to a file.

Answer (score 2):

i can just set flag :

```
-Dverbose
```

or if you want to see all logs :

```
-Dall
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can also put the following into a snmp.conf file and twiddle the options there too:

```
debugTokens nstAgentSubagentObject
doDebugging 1
```

But, the other answer is spot on: you need to turn on debugging where the code will be hit, which is in the subagent (the snmp.conf file will be read by both).